# SplitViewController's popover UI error when UISearchBar is in focus

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, popover

When a splitview is in portrait mode, the rootView shows as a popover.
in this case, my rootView has a tableView with a searchBar at the top. When I tapped the search bar, the keyboard appears, and the splitView's popover automatically adjust its height, but at the same time, I get this in the top of the popover..

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. apparently we have to post this question to get the answer :D, 
This behavior was caused by the popover's content: there is a tableView whose cells
have some custom content. There was a tag assigned for each content, and those tags where numbers from 1 to 5... And that's it!!! when we change the tags from 1 to 5 and set those from 101 to 105 the popover get fixed.

It's not the first time we get this kind of errors related to tag values. So be careful with the tags you're using!!!! =P

Hope this helps.